# Output multiline textbox to variable in PowerShell WinForm

Tags: winforms, powershell, split, textbox, richtextbox

I have a WinForm in PowerShell where email contents are copied into a multiline textbox, output to a variable, and sent to a recipient on button press.

Everything works perfectly except the content from the textbox does not remain multiline.

Is it possible to extract the entered text and output in the same format?

I've attempted using TextBox and RichTextBox, splitting etc but unable to get it to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try pulling `$textBox.Lines` instead of `$textBox.Text`.
This will give you an array of textlines in the box you can join together with the appropriate newline:

```
# for normal text:
$textEntered = $textBox.Lines -join [Environment]::NewLine

# for HTML:
$textEntered = $textBox.Lines -join '<br />'
```

Comment: Thank you so much - it was THAT easy! I used the HTML one to send the email.